# Record the last JButton pressed in a grid of JButtons

Tags: java, swing

Hey guys here's the deal I am trying to create a simple chess game using java. I have my board of an [8][8] array of JButtons. I assign each a new SquareListener which is a class that extends BoardListner which a super class that implements Action Listener. I want to record whether or not the button that is currently being pressed is equal to the last button that was pressed. I am storing the JButton instance that is pressed in the super class and referring to that in the SqaureListener actionPerformed method. Here is the example of the classes that I created for the buttons.

```
public class SquareListener extends BoardListener {
private int row;
private int column;


public SquareListener(int row, int column){
    this.setRow(row);
    this.setColumn(column);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    JButton buttonPressed = (JButton) ae.getSource();
    if(buttonPressed == super.lastButtonPressed){
        System.out.println("This is the button you last pressed");
    }else{
        System.out.println("This is a new button");
    }
    super.lastButtonPressed = buttonPressed;
}
```

and here is the super class where I am storing the isSelecting data

```
public class BoardListener implements ActionListener {

    private boolean isSelectingInsteadOfTargeting = true;
    JButton lastButtonPressed = new JButton();

    @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public boolean isSelectingInsteadOfTargeting() {
        return isSelectingInsteadOfTargeting;
    }

    public void setSelectingInsteadOfTargeting(boolean isSelectingInsteadOfTargeting) {
    this.isSelectingInsteadOfTargeting = isSelectingInsteadOfTargeting;
    }

}
```

I would expect for each time a button is pressed to have a instance of that button passed into buttonPressed and compared to what's stored in BoardListener, to then have that printed out and then to assign buttonPressed to the super member. Instead I am getting the behavior where if I press a button once it will always return "This is the button you last pressed" even If I had pressed a new one in between. Is there something wrong with the way I'm going about this? Is there any easier way?

here is the additional code where I store the buttons and assign them the action listeners

```
public Board(boolean _isWhite){
    gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8,8));
    chessBoardSquares = new Square[8][8];
    boolean shouldBeWhite = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for(int j= 0; j < 8; j++){
            Square square = new Square(i,j);
            square.getButton().addActionListener(new SquareListener(i,j));
            if(shouldBeWhite){
                square.getButton().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                shouldBeWhite = false;
            }else{
                square.getButton().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                shouldBeWhite = true;
            }
            if (j == 7){
                shouldBeWhite = !shouldBeWhite;
            }
            chessBoardSquares[i][j] = square;
            gui.add(chessBoardSquares[i][j].getButton());
        }
    }
    BoardFactory boardFactory = new BoardFactory();
    if(_isWhite){
        updateBoardIconsBasedOnCurrentBoardArray(boardFactory.getBlackStartArray());
    }else{
        //getblack start array and invoke method to change button icons based on array
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you register the Listeners to your Buttons. I suspect you've 64 distinct Listeners for each of the buttons. In this case, i think there there should be a Board class, which can track the latest and previous button click as a static variable.

Comment: just added it let me know what you think I obviously have some other supplementary classes but you can probably get the gist from this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each button has its own listener, and each listener has its own lsstButonPressed field, so that can't work.

Use the same listener *instance* for all buttons, or store the last button pressed in the board (or in another object shared by all the listeners).

Also, you don't need `super` to access the lastButtonPressed.

And this

```
JButton lastButtonPressed = new JButton();
```

creates a new JButton for nothing. Just leave the field to null.

Comment: should i use static fields in the board class to store global click data?

Comment: No. A non-static instance field would be a better idea.

Comment: Ok but the problem i ran into is how to have a seperate action listener for each button but have them actually change the Board object i instantiate in main. If it's a non-static instance field how could the action listeners manipulate those fields outside of the main method?

Comment: Pass the board (or an object containing last button pressed of the board) to the constructor of the listeners.

Comment: how would something like that look? If I am constructing 64 action listeners and passing in the board object into each one wouldn't I have a seperate instance of the board in each listener? Also how would i manipulate non-static members of the board? for instance on press if i move a pawn how can i change the target squares icon to update with the move? I am relatively new to OOP and very new to swing so forgive me if these are trivial questions I just haven't grasped everything yet

Comment: No. You would pass **the** board object (i.e. `this`), and all 64 listeners would thus each have a reference to the same board object. Just like, when doing `Board b1 = new Board(); b2 = b1;`, b1 and b2 are two references to the same Board object. When you have a reference to an object, you can call its methods, like for example `board.setLastButtonPressed((JButton) event.getSource())`.

Comment: oh wow that actually makes a lot of sense, I guess my natural follow up would be now that i'm passing in this to each listener, in the listener how can i call methods on that board object outside of the constructor, i definitely dont want to instantiate a new board, should my actionPerformmed method be inside of the constructor?

Comment: In the constructor, store the board passed as argument in a field of the listener. Once it's stored in a field, the actionPerformed() method of the listener (or any other method), can access the field.

Answer (score 4):

We don't need a whole grid of 8 x 8, but maybe a 2 x 2 that can be scaled to 8 x 8 by you.

This code compares the last coords of the button clicked.

You might use a single `ActionListener` for all your buttons...

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TwiceButtonPressed {

    private JFrame frame;

    private JButton[][] buttons;

    private JLabel label;
    private JLabel sameButtonLabel;

    private JPanel pane;

    private boolean sameButtonPressed;

    private static final int rows = 2;
    private static final int cols = 2;

    private int buttonRow = -1;
    private int buttonCol = -1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new TwiceButtonPressed().createAndShowGui()); 
    }

    public void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());

        sameButtonPressed = false;

        label = new JLabel("Button pressed: NONE");
        sameButtonLabel = new JLabel("Same button pressed: " + sameButtonPressed);

        pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols));

        buttons = new JButton[rows][cols];

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                buttons[i][j] = new JButton(i + "" + j);
                buttons[i][j].addActionListener(listener);
                pane.add(buttons[i][j]);
            }
        }

        frame.add(sameButtonLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                    if (e.getSource().equals(buttons[i][j])) {
                        label.setText("Button pressed: " + buttons[i][j].getText());
                        System.out.println(buttonRow + "==" + i + "***" + buttonCol + "==" + j);
                        if (buttonRow == i && buttonCol == j) {
                            sameButtonPressed = true;
                        } else {
                            sameButtonPressed = false;
                        }
                        sameButtonLabel.setText("Same button pressed: " + sameButtonPressed);
                        buttonRow = i;
                        buttonCol = j;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

[image]

Also, you might change your white / black algorithm to something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        buttons[i][j] = new JButton() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(50, 50);
            }
        };
        buttons[i][j].addActionListener(listener);
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            if (j % 2 == 0) {
                buttons[i][j].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            } else {
                buttons[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }
        } else {
            if (j % 2 != 0) {
                buttons[i][j].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            } else {
                buttons[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
        pane.add(buttons[i][j]);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer this was really helpful, Do you think my white/black algorithm is inefficient/wrong? I figured since it works its fine. Is that mentality bad for more difficult algorithms i might write in the future?

Comment: @BrendanRobert not that it's inneficient, but harder to understand / read. It does the same as mine, I was just showing you another way of doing it. I hope that helps you :)